# Можно ли придумать скрипт для подключения и отключения жестких дисков в Windows?

Tags: windows, сервер

Хочу на рабочем сервере сделать бекапные диски длительного хранения.
Идея такая раз в месяц срабатывает скрипт подключает жесткие диски или рейд в систему и делает бекап. Потом отключает жесткие диски от системы.

Цель этих действий. Отрезать какой либо доступ к жесткому диску как будто он физически отключен на случай если организация нахватает вирусни или еще чего.

Через powershell или что нибудь подобное можно это провернуть?

Upd: Имею ввиду делать архивацию всех бекапов (ежедневных, месячных, годовых) раз в месяц.

Comment: Нет смысла. Бэкап может начаться как раз в тот момент, когда "организация нахватает вирусни или еще чего". А в остальном более чем достаточно штатного ограничения прав доступа.

Comment: Вы видимо не сталкивались с подобными случаями. Гораздо лучше иметь бекапы на отрезанном от инфраструктуры жёстком чем не иметь. Плюс вероятность что какая то фигня залетит и не будет обнаружена раз в месяц определённый промежуток времени, гораздо меньше. Ну и даже ограничение прав не всегда спасает.

Comment: Бэкапы раз в месяц? Серьёзно?

Comment: *Вы видимо не сталкивались с подобными случаями.* С бэкапами раз в месяц? с единственным носителем для бэкапа? конечно, не сталкивался... на предыдущей работе у меня были ежедневные бэкапы, три копии, причём две - в разных помещениях, а третья вообще на другой промзоне. *какая то фигня залетит и не будет обнаружена раз в месяц* обычное время автоматического реагирования на известную угрозу - менее секунды, на подозрительную активность - не более 5 минут.

Comment: Я говорю не о регулярных бекапах, а о одном бекапе раз в месяц всего архива бекапов(ежедневные, месячные и т.д.)

Comment: @Oxyd Обновил пост я немного не правильно изложил мысль.

Comment: @AleksandrLobanov Короче... Как говорилось в одном советском фильме... «Я тебя полюбил, я тебя научу»© Берёте какой-нибудь свободный компьютер, из списанных или из обменного фонда. Ставите туда эти ваши диски. Ставите туда операционку по вкусу(Linux, *BSD, Windows) и сервер централизованной системы резервного копирования, например [Bareos](https://bareos.org/), в девичестве, Bacula, а на ваш сервер соответственно агента bacula, настраиваете, попутно изучая существующие политики резервного копирования, радуетесь жизни! А то что вы пытаетесь придумать вас никак не защитит от потери данных.

Comment: @Oxyd Про Bareos загуглю спасибо. Вообще Убунту сервер + самба +apm  люблю могу умею практикую и это в действительности решает мою задачу, но в моем кейсе жизнь дописывает условия делать из того что есть.)

Comment: Старший коллега пользуется `BorgBackup`.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, вообщем, как я уже говорил, то что вы пытаетесь сделать это, простите за каламбур, сделать лишь-бы сделать Никаких практических профитов от этого нет... Открываете консоль cmd `diskpart`, потом смотрим список дисков `list disk`, потом выбираем нужный диск, по номеру, например 2-й `select disk 2` Вырубаем... `offline disk` Как делать скрипты и включить диск обратно, смотреть [в офф доках от MS](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart-scripts-and-examples), по ключевому слову diskpart в поиске.